# Is there a way to use cascading rules for RSpec HTTP stubs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I am writing a unit test for a method that calls multiple http requests to an external service.

It starts by calling an index route, say "http://api.com/things"

Then it goes through each element in the index and calls the 'show route', say it's "http://api.com/things/123"

You see, the only difference is the `/123` at the end of the "show" route.

Now I have a stub for the index route.

```
   WebMock::API.stub_request(
      :get,
      /.*api\.com\/things.*/
    ).to_return(<something>)
```

The problem is that this intercepts the calls to the "show" route.

I want to make a different mock for the "show" route. I would like to not have to dive into regex to do this.

Is there a way you can set up http mocks in the same way that routes work in Sinatra or Rails - in other words, if there's a match higher up in the file the the lower ones won't be hit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex isn't complicated, and would be mutually exclusive so should work fine.

For the index

```
   WebMock::API.stub_request(
      :get,
      /.*api\.com\/things$/
    ).to_return(<something>)
```

For the show

```
   WebMock::API.stub_request(
      :get,
      /.*api\.com\/things\/\d/
    ).to_return(<something>)
```

Comment: Given the information in my question your answer is correct. I suppose it's my fault for not showing my actual application code, but I had to change this a bit to make it work. `to_return` can take a block (which gets passed the url)  so in there, I did something like `if url.include?("123") <do x> else <do y>`.

Comment: Well, yes, your request was for a different mock for `show` versus `index`but that's cool, as long as you got a solution.